# find a key such that its corresponding values are all the distinct values in another table

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables that look like this:

`STUDENT(*snum: integer, sname: string, deptid: integer, slevel: string, age: integer)`

`CLASS(*cname: string, meets_at: date, room: string, fid: integer)`

`ENROLLED(*snum: integer, *cname: string)`

I am trying to find student names(sname) of students, who have classes in all the rooms(room in CLASS). How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
select sname from STUDENT
join ENROLLED on STUDENT.snum = ENROLLED.snum
join CLASS on ENROLLED.cname = CLASS.cname
group by sname
having count(distinct room) = (select count(distinct room) from CLASS)
```

SQLfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71cba/1/0

You should probably have ROOMS as a separate table, to avoid problems with room names being typed inconsistently.